# How can I underline specific text in a node of Mermaid Markdown in GitLab?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

When using [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/#/flowchart?id=nodes-amp-shapes) in a README.md in gitlab, one can create a node containing text, seperated by newlines, like this.

````
```mermaid
A(List<br/>Item One<br/>Item Two<br/>Item Three)
```
````

My question is how could I underline just one section of this text?

Specifically, how could I underline the first line, i.e. the list header.